# $\frac37x + \frac{3\times6}{7\times10}x^2 + \frac{3\times6\times9}{7\times10\times13}x^3+ \cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Convergence of the series for $x>0$:

$$\frac37x + \frac{3\times6}{7\times10}x^2 + \frac{3\times6\times9}{7\times10\times13}x^3+ \cdots$$

The general tem  is $a_n = \frac{3\times6\times \cdots \times(3+(n-1)3)}{7\times10 \times\cdots \times(7+(n-1)3)} x^n$.

I am thinking of using Raabe's Test. but cannot proceed.

We have to find $$\lim _{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1} } -1\right) = \lim _{n \to \infty} n \left(\frac{7+3n}{3+3n} \frac1x -1\right)$$

so the limit depends upon $x$.

Comment: Note that $a_n = \Theta (n^{-4/3}).$ From this, you can just use the ratio test.

Comment: Here is a fun fact.  The series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,x^k\,\prod_{j=1}^k\,\frac{3j}{3j+4}$$ is convergent for, and only for, all complex numbers $x$ such that $|x|<1$ and it is equal to $$-1+\frac{4}{x}+\frac{2\,(1-x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{3\,x^{\frac{4}{3}}}\,g(x)\,$$ where $$g(x):=\small 2\sqrt{3}\,\text{atan2}\left(1-\frac{x^{\frac13}}{2\,(1-x)^{\frac13}},-\frac{\sqrt{3}\,x^{\frac13}}{2\,(1-x)^{\frac13}}\right)-2\ln\left(1+\frac{x^{\frac13}}{(1-x)^{\frac13}}\right)+\ln\left(1-\frac{x^{\frac13}}{(1-x)^{\frac13}}+\frac{x^{\frac23}}{(1-x)^{\frac23}}\right)\,.$$

Comment: In the comment above, $\text{atan2}$ is the [$2$-argument arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).  Indeed, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,x^k\,\prod_{j=1}^k\,\frac{3j}{3j+4}={_2F_1}\left(1,1;\frac{7}{3};x\right)-1\text{ for every }x\in\mathbb{C}\text{ such that }|x|<1\,,$$ where ${_2F_1}$ denotes the [hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html).  I got this from Mathematica, unfortunately, so I don't know how to resolve the hypergeometric function manually.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n = \frac{3\times6\times \cdots \times(3+(n-1)3)}{7\times10 \times\cdots \times(7+(n-1)3)} x^n$$

Then $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} =\frac{3n+3}{3n+7} x = \frac{3+\frac3n}{3 + \frac7n}x$$

From Ratio test we can conclude that when $|x| <1$ the series is convergent and when $|x|>1$ the series is divergent. Ratio Test can't conclude anything for $x = 1$. Here we use Raabe's Test.

$$\lim _{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1} } -1\right) = \lim _{n \to \infty} n \left(\frac{7+3n}{3+3n}  -1\right) = \lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{4n}{3+3n} = \frac43 >1$$ and hence the series is convergent.